# Update an array of strings nested within an array of objects in mongodb

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, object, nested

I want to update an array of strings which is nested inside an array of Objects.

This is my Mongo document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a52d995734d1d388d17eb0b"),
    "teams" : [ 
        {
            "assignedModels" : [ 
                "5a1665a82c7eb90001a7d676", 
                "58d8fc2d734d1d5af6dd4803"
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "assignedModels" : [ 
                "58d8fc2d734d1d5af6dd4803"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Now i want to remove ***"58d8fc2d734d1d5af6dd4803"*** string from the assignedModels of each team object.

I have already tried some queries, but nothing is working as i expected

**Current query:**

```
db.collection('organisations').updateMany(
    { _id: database.ObjectID("5a52d995734d1d388d17eb0b") ,'teams.assignedModels' : { $exists:true } },
    { $pull : {'teams.$.assignedModels' : "58d8fc2d734d1d5af6dd4803" } },
    { multi: true });
```

**Current output:**

updated the 0th element of the teams array correctly but does not traverse through the other objects.

i tried ***$[], teams.assignedModels***  as well

**Expected output:**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a52d995734d1d388d17eb0b"),
    "teams" : [ 
        {
            "assignedModels" : [ 
                "5a1665a82c7eb90001a7d676"
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "assignedModels" : [ 
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Which version of MongoDB are you using?

Comment: mongod version: 3.4.10 (MMAPv1) (Mlab)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MongoDB 3.4, there is no way to do this nicely. You will need to either iterate over your elements (client-side) and update everything one-by-one. Or you could run the following query multiple times (until there are no more updates):

```
db.collection('organisations').updateMany(
    { _id: database.ObjectID("5a52d995734d1d388d17eb0b"), 'teams.assignedModels': "58d8fc2d734d1d5af6dd4803" },
    { $pull : {'teams.$.assignedModels' : "58d8fc2d734d1d5af6dd4803" } }
);
```

For MongoDB 3.6 you can simply do this:

```
db.collection('organisations').updateMany(
    { _id: database.ObjectID("5a52d995734d1d388d17eb0b") },
    { $pull : {'teams.$[].assignedModels' : "58d8fc2d734d1d5af6dd4803" } }
);
```

There's a catch, though, in case you're updating your MongoDB v3.4 to v3.6 which is documented [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.6-compatibility/#backwards-incompatible-features):

> 3.6 deployments have the following default featureCompatibilityVersion values: [...] For deployments upgraded from 3.4: "3.4" until you
>   setFeatureCompatibilityVersion to "3.6".

So you will need to run the following command once to unleash the 3.6 power:

```
db.adminCommand( { setFeatureCompatibilityVersion: "3.6" } )
```

Comment: "there is no way to do this nicely" - is this still true?

Comment: @ghosh: As I wrote above, for MongoDB 3.4 there is no nice way. From 3.6 onwards, this can be done nicely like I also described above.